# Импорт данных с сайта с помощью Google Spreadsheet - не вытащить ссылки

Tags: html, google-spreadsheet

Не получается вытащить ссылки. Мне кажется, сложность в DOM-дереве, возможно, я что-то упускаю, хотя перебрала кучу вариантов. Помогите, пожалуйста

=IMPORTXML("https://cyberleninka.ru/journal/n/peterburgskiy-istoricheskiy-zhurnal#/1036034";"//ul[@class='list']//li/a/@href")

Из такой ссылки, например, без проблем: 
https://cyberleninka.ru/article/c/informatika

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы проверить, что может "вытягивать" `IMPORTXML`, воспользуйтесь любой возможностью отключения JS в вашем браузере. Например, для Google Chrome я испльзую [Quick Javascript Switcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-javascript-switcher/geddoclleiomckbhadiaipdggiiccfje)

Обратите внимание, что в первом случае ссылок нет, а по той ссылке, где нет проблем, при отключении JS ссылки остаются. Значит их можно получить через `IMPORTXML`.